# MonoGame: 2D Sprite acting weirdly

Tags: c#, sprites, monogame

I have a double array of tiles that show the ground.
They are randomly populated with a variety of items.

one item that only spawns one is a creature spawner.

this spawner spawns up to 5 creatures (for testing it does all 5 immediately).

these creatures move around randomly every update.

i know for a fact they are moving independent of each other.

but the weird part is, sometimes i only see 1 or 2 of the 5. the others arent there. console output tells me there is in fact 5.

and, additionally, when there is all 5, some of them get cut off if they move too far in one direction. but only SOME of them. ive seen two different creatures move in the same direction and only one of them got cut off.

to further complicate things, i believe some of the items on the ground are disappearing shortly after the world is created, including the spawner. sometimes i never even see the spawner, but the creatures are still created 'properly'.

i have in the initialization section to randomly generate the world, including all the items and where the spawner is.

after that is done, in the Update section, it checks if a tile contains an updateable object (currently, spawner is the only one). if it does, that objects calls its update method.

after that is done, the creatures are updated, if any.

then it is drawn. background tiles then ground objects then creatures.

if anyone has any idea what i might need to change to fix it or require any further information, just let me know, and thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be your drawing order, check out the layer parameter in spritebatch and what sprite sort mode you are using. Some code snippets may help too.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question isn't easy to answer because you've only posted a description of the problem without any code. At this point we can only guess as to what the problem might be and you won't get very good answers. Please try to [ask a better question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That said, my gut feeling says you've probably initialized `Random` in the wrong spot.